# Issue Running Distributed Play Framework Project

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I have `dist` my play framework project and deploy on my production server. However, when try to run the project I'm getting an ambiguous error; I have searched around to see a way out, but it obvious am not getting an better result.

Instruction of my approach is as follows:

1. Project is `dist` to a zip file and uploaded to my production server.
2. While running the code /path/to/dist-project/projectName -Dconfig.resource=root-prod.conf -Dhttp.port=9008 &

**OUTPUT RESULT**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.SUPPORTED_CIPHERS from class io.netty.handler.ssl.NettySslPackageAccessor
>       at io.netty.handler.ssl.NettySslPackageAccessor.jdkSupportedCipherSuites(NettySslPackageAccessor.java:24)
>       at org.asynchttpclient.config.AsyncHttpClientConfigDefaults.defaultEnabledCipherSuites(AsyncHttpClientConfigDefaults.java:85)
>       at org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder.(DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.java:635)
>       at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcConfigBuilder.(AhcConfig.scala:126)
>       at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClient$.apply(AhcWS.scala:71)
>       at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSAPI.client$lzycompute(AhcWS.scala:400)
>       at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSAPI.client(AhcWS.scala:390)
>       at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSAPI.client(AhcWS.scala:386)
>       at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.WSClientProvider.get(AhcWS.scala:382)
>       at play.api.libs.ws.ahc.WSClientProvider.get(AhcWS.scala:381)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
>       at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
>       at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
>       at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
>       at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
>       at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
>       at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:47)
>       at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:22)
>       at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)